# how to access cck checkbox value from views .tpl

Tags: drupal-6, view, cck

Subject for advanced views theming:

1) Create CCK integer field "field_checkbox"  - Single on/of checkbox

Allowed values

0|No

1|Yes

2) In views row-style .tpl

```
<?php print $fields['field_checkbox_value']->content ?>
```

doesn't print any value, why?

Other fields output fine.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

In views settings field output must be **unformatted**.
Output of above function return **1**.

Useful for advanced views theming, for example:

```
<h3 class="title <?php if ($fields['field_checkbox_value']->content) print 'another-class' ?>">
  <?php print $fields['title']->content ?>
</h3>
```